# 'f2py -c --help-fcompiler' hangs

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, gfortran, f2py

When i run the command

```
f2py --c -help-fcompiler
```

f2py prints the following output and then hangs indefinitely

```
Gnu95FCompiler instance properties:
  archiver        = ['/usr/bin/gfortran', '-cr']
  compile_switch  = '-c'
  compiler_f77    = ['/usr/bin/gfortran', '-Wall', '-g', '-ffixed-form', '-
                    fno-second-underscore', '-fPIC', '-O3', '-funroll-loops']
  compiler_f90    = ['/usr/bin/gfortran', '-Wall', '-g', '-fno-second-
                    underscore', '-fPIC', '-O3', '-funroll-loops']
  compiler_fix    = ['/usr/bin/gfortran', '-Wall', '-g', '-ffixed-form', '-
                    fno-second-underscore', '-Wall', '-g', '-fno-second-
                    underscore', '-fPIC', '-O3', '-funroll-loops']
  libraries       = ['gfortran']
  library_dirs    = ['/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7', '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64
                    -linux-gnu/7']
  linker_exe      = ['/usr/bin/gfortran', '-Wall', '-Wall']
  linker_so       = ['/usr/bin/gfortran', '-Wall', '-g', '-Wall', '-g', '-
                    shared']
  object_switch   = '-o '
  ranlib          = ['/usr/bin/gfortran']
  version         = LooseVersion ('7')
  version_cmd     = ['/usr/bin/gfortran', '-dumpversion']
```

When I kill the process manually with `ctrl+c` it looks like it gets stuck here:

```
TEST_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/fcompiler/__init__.py", line 472, in customize
    posix=(os.name == 'posix'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shlex.py", line 305, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shlex.py", line 295, in __next__
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shlex.py", line 105, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shlex.py"
```

This is all inside a clean virtual environment using numpy 1.16.0

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in numpy(fixed and backported to 1.16.1):

See `https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/12843`

The reason

```
f2py -c --help-compiler
```

hangs indefinitely on Ubuntu 18.04 is as a result of `shlex.split()` being called on `None`.

This occurs at line 471 in `fcompiler/__init__.py` when `show_fcompilers()` calls `customize()` and `self.command_vars.compiler_f77 = f77`, `self.command_vars.compiler_f90 = None`